# Unexpected character '' when importing a JSX file into a JS file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a JSX file (I put it all but I don't think it's necessary):

**Selector.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MuiSelect from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
// import theme from '../theme/theme.scss';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
​
const styles = {
  formControl: {
    margin: 0,
    minWidth: 100,
    // background: theme.cloudColor,
    // borderColor: theme.lightBlueColor,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    borderRadius: '4px',
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: '14px'
  },
  select: {
    height: '48px',
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontFamily: 'CircularStd'
  },
};
​
class Select extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      error: false,
      helperText: '',
    };
  }
  createOption(key, option = {}) {
    let toggleDisabled = (key===0) ? true : false;
    return (
      <MenuItem key={key} value={option.value} disabled={toggleDisabled}>
        {option.label}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }
​
  // handleChange(event) {
  //   this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  // }
​
  render() {
    const items = [];
    let { classes, label, onChange, options, className, value, helperText, error, disabled } = this.props;
​
    if (!Array.isArray(options)) {
      options = [];
    }
​
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      items.push(this.createOption(i, options[i]));
    }
​
    let selectStyle = className + ' ' + classes.formControl;

    return (
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={selectStyle} error={error} disabled={disabled}>
        <InputLabel className={classes.inputLabel}>{label}</InputLabel>
        <MuiSelect
          value={value}
          className={classes.select}       
          onChange={event => onChange(event)}>
          {items}
        </MuiSelect>
        <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}
​
export default withStyles(styles)(Select);
```

in the same folder with this file there is a JS file, where the previous one is imported:

**myFile.js**

```
//other imports
import Selector from './Selector.jsx';

...

render() {

  return(
     <Selector></Selector>
     ...
  )
}
```

it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/orderTable/Selector.jsx
  Line 9:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected character '​'

   7 | // import theme from '../theme/theme.scss';
   8 | import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
>  9 | ​
     | ^
  10 | const styles = {
  11 |   formControl: {
  12 |     margin: 0,
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some hidden char on your code in line number 9, 28, 46, 50, 54, 58, 62, 79. If you press backspace from your keyboard on those line, you will see nothing is erased but actually that hidden char was erased. I am not sure what is that. but I erased all those hidden char and the code is working. Please check the following code that is exactly your code except those hidden character.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MuiSelect from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
// import theme from '../theme/theme.scss';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  formControl: {
    margin: 0,
    minWidth: 100,
    // background: theme.cloudColor,
    // borderColor: theme.lightBlueColor,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    borderRadius: '4px',
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: '14px'
  },
  select: {
    height: '48px',
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontFamily: 'CircularStd'
  },
};

class Select extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      error: false,
      helperText: '',
    };
  }
  createOption(key, option = {}) {
    let toggleDisabled = (key===0) ? true : false;
    return (
      <MenuItem key={key} value={option.value} disabled={toggleDisabled}>
        {option.label}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }

  // handleChange(event) {
  //   this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  // }

  render() {
    const items = [];
    let { classes, label, onChange, options, className, value, helperText, error, disabled } = this.props;

    if (!Array.isArray(options)) {
      options = [];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      items.push(this.createOption(i, options[i]));
    }

    let selectStyle = className + ' ' + classes.formControl;

    return (
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={selectStyle} error={error} disabled={disabled}>
        <InputLabel className={classes.inputLabel}>{label}</InputLabel>
        <MuiSelect
          value={value}
          className={classes.select}
          onChange={event => onChange(event)}>
          {items}
        </MuiSelect>
        <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Select);
```